# Loop through a combination of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to think of a way to loop through a number of combinations making sure that I go through each available combination without repeat. Let me explain. I have a set of numbers, for example

```
20,000
25,000
27,000
29,000
```

and I would like to alter this set of numbers via a loop and copy the new numbers into a different sheet so that my formulas on that sheet can calculate whatever I need them to calculate. For example, the first couple of iterations might look something like this:

```
1st
20,000 x 1.001
25,000 x 1
27,000 x 1
29,000 x 1

2nd
20,002 x 1.001
25,000 x 1.001
27,000 x 1
29,000 x 1
```

The first row of numbers should never exceed the second. So 20,000 should only go as high as 25,000.

I was able to set up a system whereby I set up a matrix and then loop through a random set of combinations using =rand() however this does not ensure I hit every combination and also repeats combinations.

Can anyone explain the math behind this and also how I would use a loop to accomplish my goal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with smaller numbers.

See if this works for you.

```
Sub looper()


'First Array
Dim myArray(9) As Double

For i = 1 To 10

myArray(i - 1) = i

Next i


'Second Array
Dim myOtherArray(9) As Double

For i = 1 To 10

myOtherArray(i - 1) = i

Next i


'Loop through each one
For Each slot In myArray


For Each otherSlot In myOtherArray


Debug.Print (slot & " * " & otherSlot & " = " & slot * otherSlot)


Next otherSlot


Next slot


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

GD user1813558,

Your question contains too little detail and is too broadly scoped to be able to provide a accurate answer.

- Are your numbers arbitrary (i.e. the ones you provided are 'just'
  samples) or will they be fixed as per your indicated numbers ?
- Will there always be only 4 numbers ?
- Is the distribution of your startnumbers (i.e. their difference
  value)   always as per your indication  0, +5000, +2000, +2000
- Will the results of all 'loops' (or iterations) need to be copied to
  a different sheet ? (i.e looping from 20.000 to 25.000 by increments
  of 1.001 would require about 223 iterations, and subsequently sheets,
  before the result starts exceeding 25.000 ?)
- Does a new sheet need to be created for each iteration result or are they
  existent or will the result be copied to the same sheet for every iteration ?

In short, please provide a more accurate question.